# How to normalise the area under two curves to become equal to 1 in r

Tags: r

I have two plots and I need to normalise (the area under the curve =1) each of them individually and then together. I tried

```
 N1 = (x1 - mean(x1))/sd(x1) 
 N2 = (x2 - mean(x2))/sd(x2)
```

but I am not sure if this is the right thing to do?
Also, How to merge these two plot and normalise them into one plot?

How about this

```
A = diff(y1)*rollmean(x1,2) 
riemann_sum = sum(A) 
yn = cumsum(A) /riemann_sum 
yn = c(0,yn) plot(y1,yn ) 
plot(y1, c(0, diff(yn)/ diff(x1) )
```

Comment: You want to plot N1 ad N2 against x1 and x2 respectively?

Comment: I want to plot y1,x1 and y2,x2 but my question is how to normalise x1,x2 each one alone then normalise them together in one plot ?

Comment: Seems fine to me, just make sure your x and y limits allow both plots to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. A density of a continuous random variable is (traditionally) always normalised such that the integral over the density (i.e. area under curve) equals to one.

Density plots in R will be normalised such the area under curve equals to one. There exist some nice posts here on SO that explicitly demonstrate that point; see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876219/calculating-an-area-under-a-continuous-density-plot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701560/why-is-the-sum-of-the-area-under-density-curve-always-greater-than-1-r).

Your code example seems to refer to *standardising* (Z score scaling) random variables. I assume you're asking about how to visualise the density of two standardised random variables.

Here is a simple example:

1. We sample data from two normal distributions, each with different mean and sd.

   ```
   set.seed(2018);
   x1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 3);
   x2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 4);
   ```
2. We show a density plot of the normalised (i.e. Z-scaled) values:

   ```
   library(tidyverse);
   data.frame(x1 = scale(x1), x2 = scale(x2)) %>%
       gather(key, value) %>%
       ggplot(aes(value, fill = key)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.4);
   ```

   [image]

   Note that `scale` does the same as `(x - mean(x)) / sd(x)`.

Comment: How about this ?   A = diff(y1)*rollmean(x1,2)
riemann_sum = sum(A)
yn  = cumsum(A) /riemann_sum

 yn  = c(0,yn)
 plot(y1,yn )
 plot(y1, c(0, diff(yn)/ diff(x1) )

Comment: @Armani ??? I'm not following. What are you trying to demonstrate? That the area under curve of the density of a random variable equals to  one? If so, this is a duplicate question, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876219/calculating-an-area-under-a-continuous-density-plot), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701560/why-is-the-sum-of-the-area-under-density-curve-always-greater-than-1-r). Normalisation and standardisation of a random variable are two different things. Also please don't post code in comments; instead edit your original post.

Comment: I would like to normalise the two plots because of this I was not sure about whether the standardisation bit.

Comment: If you show a *density plot* of your random variable the curve will be normalised such that the area under the curve equals to one. Perhaps `density` is what you're after? Take a look at `?density` and the other SO posts I link to.

Comment: Thank you Maurits Evers.

Comment: You're very welcome @Amani. Please consider closing this question by setting the check mark next to the solution.